# custom generic collection- what is the best way to refactor it?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a similar problem and tried to depict it with code as it is easier to explain.

Basically I have a generic collection, so irrespective of which type of collection its instantiated as, it will have some common properties and events. And I am interested in these common properties.

Say, I have the instantiated obect of the generic collection - what is the best way to get these properties and subscribe to the events? I understand I can do it by implementing an interface and casting it to the interface definition but I don't like doing that as I am just doing it to please a single requirement. Is there a better way to refactor this?

```
public interface IDoNotLikeThisInterfaceDefinitionJustToPleaseGetDetailMethod
{
    string Detail { get; }

    event Action<bool> MyEvent;
}

public class MyList<T> : List<T>
    //, IDoNotLikeThisInterfaceDefinitionJustToPleaseGetDetailMethod
{
    public string Detail
    {
        get;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyList<int> mi = new MyList<int>();
        MyList<string> ms = new MyList<string>();
        MyList<char> mc = new MyList<char>();
        GetDetail(mi);
        GetDetail(ms);
        GetDetail(mc);
    }

    //please note that obect need not be mylist<t>
    static string DoSomeWork(Object object)
    {
        //Problem: I know myListObect is generic mylist
        //but i dont know which type of collection it is
        //and in fact i do not care
        //all i want is get the detail information

        //what is the best way to solve it
        //i know one way to solve is implement an interface and case it to get details
        var foo = myListObject as IDoNotLikeThisInterfaceDefinitionJustToPleaseGetDetailMethod;
        if (foo != null)
        {
            //is there another way?
            //here i also need to subsribe to the event as well?
            return foo.Detail;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding using `mi.Detail` directly?

Comment: becuase i dont have reference to mylist<T>. getdetail(...) is just an example and its totally in different context altogether.

Comment: For the future - you should, in general, provide the context within the question - Your question, as written, suggests a generic method would work, as your example code would work this way.

Comment: @Reed, i just tried to simplify the question and tried to avoid unnecessary details. But looks like i have over simplified the problem - yes, wil add more details in future :) As of now, i am just using interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your method generic:

```
static string GetDetail<T>(MyList<T> myList)
{
    return myList.Detail;
}
```

This will allow you to call it with the same code you already have written, and completely eliminate the interface.

---

Edit in response to comments:

Given that you don't know the type, and you're just checking against an `object`, it does seem like an interface is the best approach here.  Providing a common interface allows you to expose all of the members you need regardless of what's contained within the collection, which provides the correct behavior.

Comment: thanks Reed. But all i have is object. i dont have a referne to MyList<T>. And also i need to subscribe to some events.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `GetDetail` method generic:

```
static string GetDetail<T>(MyList<T> list)
{
    return list.Detail;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just re-read that. I was trying to solve for an unknown type `object` in the `GetDetail(object)` method. :) Yours and Reed's solution is definitely the way to go.

Comment: thanks Chris. You are correct. i have only obect with me. the getdetail(bbect) do not have reference to mylist<T>. And also i need to subsribe to some events. I have updated the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I've assumed that there are potentially multiple collection classes involved. If there's actually only *one* class - `MyList<T>` - then using a generic method is absolutely the right way to go.

> i understand i can do it by implementating an interface and casting it to the interface defenition but i dont like it as i am just doing it to please one single requirement.

You're doing it to express what the collections have in common. Unless the common members are implementing an interface, they just happen to have the same name - the interface shows that they have the same intended *meaning* too.

Using an interface is the right way to go here - but it's not clear why your `GetDetail` method doesn't just take the interface as a parameter... assuming you need the method at all.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, I know - but I think I misread the question as there being various collection classes, which would all implement the interface.

Comment: Yes, the GetDetail method is just an example. THe list is basically a datasource for a listcontrol. I want to subscribe to some events and get some proeprties. as you can see anyone can set their datasource to any type and i just happen to use my own generic list as i do some specialization while loading etc... (thread safe way to load data etcc...)

Comment: @Dreamer: It sounds like there's quite a bit of context which it would be worth including in the original question at this point...